# getting 302 while using a POST method in rest assured

Tags: post, methods, rest-assured

I have written my test case as below and got the below error,

Error in Log:

> FAILED: setpassword java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
>   Expected status code <200> but was <302>.

Code:

```
@Test(enabled=true)

public void setpassword(){
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification= new Config().getRequestSpecification();
    RequestSpecification requestHeaders= new Config().getHeaders();

    Map<String,String> password = new HashMap<String, String>();
    password.put("password", "Password@2017");
        given().spec(requestSpecification).spec(requestHeaders).body(password).when().post("https://example.com/testplatform@example.com/password").
    then().statusCode(200).log().all();


}
```

Comment: Whats the question here? Your test failed because you were expecting a 200 HTTP response, but got a 302 redirect. Seems like a valid reason for it to fail.

Comment: the same api gives me 200 in Postman. The  problem here is when there is an email in the api, it gives 302 error. I want to know if there is a way to handle such a case.

Comment: i found that "@" in the email is getting encoded as %40 and so the api is returning a 302 error. Is there a way i can prevent that from happening? Thanks for the help in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

i solved the issue. I was getting a 302 error because the api url was getting encoded. i used urlEncodingEnabled(false) and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
given().log().all().contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                .redirects().follow(false).redirects().max(100) 
                .queryParam()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in my case, I had url with JWT token to test the lin/website. It brought to my attention that I did not use url + JWT as a complete link. I disregard the JWT, used only the link so it did not redirect the website.